# currying - how to get the count of args?

Tags: javascript

in a sum function that returns the sum of (1)(2)(3), (1,2)(2) as well as (1,2), how do I write logic to determine if there were just one argument (1,2) or there were more than one (1,2)(2) or (1)(2)(3) in order to return the value properly

```js
function sum (...x) {
  let total = 0;

  if (x.length > 1) {
    total += x.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  } else {
    total += x;
  }
  // return total if no other arguments;
  
  return (y) => {
    total += y;
    // return total if no other arguments;

    return (z) => {
      total += z;
      // return total if no other arguments;
    }
  }
}

sum(1,2);
sum(1,2)(3);
```

Comment: how many arguments do you expect?

Comment: Are you asking how `sum(1,2)` should know whether to evaluate to a function or a scalar, based on context?

Comment: if it is a variatic number of argument well you can't really curry, since you can't know how many arguments that function can have. UNLESS you put as a condition than the sum is calculated when sum is called with no arguments. Easy to check.

Comment: You can't have `sum(1, 2)` both return the value 3 and return a function so that `sum(1, 2)(2)` gives back 5.  (There are some tricks with `valueOf` for numeric functions, but I would never recommend them.)  Libraries like [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com) (disclaimer: I'm an author) do this for fixed-arity functions.  But there's no real way to do it for variadic ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The trick is that for example logging a value such as:

```
 console.log(
  sum(1),
  sum(1)(2) 
 );
```

tries to turn the function into a string, so it is actually the same as:

```
 console.log( 
   sum(1).toString(),
   sum(1)(2).toString()
);
```

So you just have to set a custom `toString` method to the returned function, e.g.:

```
 function sum(...values) {
  let result = values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  function curry(...values) {
    return sum(result, ...values);
  }
  curry.toString = () => "" + result; // <<
  return curry;
 }
```

Comment: pretty awesome. trying to understand it still